# Continue a "ctrl-z"-ed job in background

Tags: bash, job-control

**Is it possible to continue a stopped background job in background?**

I have a process running, I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> to stop it and return to bash. If I want to continue it, there's `fg` command available but that brings the job back to front. Is it possible to keep it in background but running, like it would have been run with `&` in the first place.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**`bg`**

See also "JOB CONTROL" in [`bash`'s manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control).

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294471/backgrounded-job-keeps-stopping